# Update case class from incomplete JSON with Argonaut or Circe

Tags: json, scala, shapeless, argonaut, circe

I need to create an updated instance from a case class instance (with any needed `DecodeJson`s implicitly derived), given an incomplete json (some fields missing). How can this be accomplished with Argonaut (preferably) or Circe (if I have to)?

Example:

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int)
val person = Person("mr complete", 42)
val incompletePersonJson = """{"name":"mr updated"}"""
val updatedPerson = updateCaseClassFromIncompleteJson(person, incompletePersonJson)

println(updatedPerson)
//yields Person(mr updated, 42)
```

I'm pretty sure I have to parse the json to json AST, then convert it to Shapeless `LabelledGeneric`, then use Shapeless update somehow to update the case class instance.

---

**Edit 2**

After reading the Shapeless source I found that I can generate my own "Default"-object. I managed to create a solution which requires the instance of the case class to be present while parsing the json. I was hoping to avoid this and instead provide the instance later. Anyway here it is:

```
import shapeless._
import argonaut._
import ArgonautShapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object MkDefault {

  object toSome extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[P] = at[P](Some(_))
  }

  def apply[P, L <: HList, D <: HList]
  (p: P)
  (implicit
   g: Generic.Aux[P, L],
   mpr: Mapper.Aux[toSome.type, L, D]
  ): Default.Aux[P, mpr.Out] =
    Default.mkDefault[P, D](mpr(g.to(p)))
}


object Testy extends App {
    implicit val defs0 = MkDefault(Person("new name? NO", 42))
    implicit def pd = DecodeJson.of[Person]
    val i = """{"name":"Old Name Kept"}"""
    val pp = Parse.decodeOption[Person](i).get
    println(pp)
}
```

This yields `Person(Old Name Kept,42)`.

Comment: Debugging ArgonautShapeless' DecodeJson inferring (ArgonautShapeless.derivedDecodeJson), i see that an object defaults=Defaults$AsOptions$$anon$9 is instantiated with values None :: None :: HNil. To me, it seems that if I could somehow replace this with an implicit instance I provide myself, I could make defaults to fill inn the missing json somehow.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would do it in a type safe way is to re-serialize your existing case class to json, convert both to a Map[String, Any], then merge the maps, convert back to json, then re-parse

Comment: @Falmarri that's actually not such a bad idea, I'll keep it in mind as a backup solution as it would obviously require more time and resources from the computer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: support for "patching" instances like this has been provided in circe since the 0.2 release:

```
import io.circe.jawn.decode, io.circe.generic.auto._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val person = Person("mr complete", 42)
val incompletePersonJson = """{"name":"mr updated"}"""

val update = decode[Person => Person](incompletePersonJson)
```

And then:

```
scala> println(update.map(_(person)))
Right(Person(mr updated,42))
```

My original [blog post](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/06/21/deriving-incomplete-type-class-instances/) about this technique uses Argonaut (mostly since I wrote it a couple of months before I started working on circe), and that implementation is [available as a library](https://github.com/travisbrown/incompletes), although I've never published it anywhere.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Switching from Argonaut to Circe in my projects now. Awesome work, keep it up :D

Comment: Noticed a significant difference from Argonaut after going back from HTTP PATCH to HTTP POST testing with Circe: default values of case classes are completely ignored in Circe, whereas in Argonaut if a field was missing from the json and had a default value, it would decode ok. Also noticed an open issue on this in Circe: https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/issues/65   Wonder if it's scheduled for a release in the near future?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate those `implicit val defs / pd` with macro annotation on `Person` (in `object Person`, for example, and do `import Person._` to summon implicits). See [this](https://github.com/Dveim/meta-simulacrum/blob/master/Simulacrum.scala) unfinished Simulacrum in scalameta (scala-reflect is fine too, but seems like scalameta can be enough here) for usage examples. Also you have to specify missing default value (`42`) somewhere, for example, in case class constructor (`age: Int = 42`, recognition can be done in macro too).

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking to avoid creating my own macros as they usually devolve into maintainence-hell, but I havent looked at scalameta or Simulacrum yet. I will keep the bounty open out today in case someone posts a non-custom-macro shapeless solution for either circe or argonaut. If no replies comes in I'll just hand you the 50 for the effort :)

Comment: I'm working on more detailed guide to scalameta-based macro annotations. Hope to finish it in ~week. "simulacrum-meta" is just an example of scalameta's APIs. Generally speaking, scalameta should be preferred over scala-reflect, if it satisfies requirements (for example, semantic API is not supported yet). In this case I think scalameta should do the job.