# Map null values to None in Scala using Circe

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, null, circe

In continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308827/update-case-class-from-incomplete-json-with-argonaut-or-circe), I have the following code but would like to map `null` JSON values to Scala None. Current behavior I am getting is that there's no difference between including a `key` with `null` `("key": null)` and not including it. I would like to map this to `None` so I can set the DB entry to `null`. Also, when a `key` is not included in the JSON, map it to existing value.

```
import io.circe.jawn.decode, io.circe.generic.auto._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int, description: Option[String])

val existingPerson = Person("mr complete", 42, Some("tall and fat"))
val incompletePersonJson = """{"description":null}"""

val update = decode[Person => Person](incompletePersonJson)
```

And then:

```
scala> println(update.map(_(existingPerson)))
Right(Person(mr updated,42,Some(tall and fat)))
```

But I would like to get:

```
Right(Person(mr updated,42,None))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution, it might be not ideal and it's not using Circe but it does the job for me:

```
def getJsonNullKeys(json: Json): List[String] = {
  json.asObject match {
    case Some(jsonObject) => jsonObject.filter(j => j._2.isNull).keys.toList
      case None => List[String]()
    }
}

if (update.isRight) {
  update.right.map(_(existingPerson)) match {
    case Right(updatedPerson) =>
      getNullKeys(incompletePersonJson).foreach { key =>
        val field = existingPerson.getClass.getDeclaredField(key)
        field.setAccessible(true)
        field.set(updatedUpdate, None)
      }
      println(updatedUpdate)
      // outputs Person(mr updated,42,None)
    case Left(error) => println(error.toString)
  }
}
```

Hope Circe adds support for this so all this boilerplate can be removed.